# Error al sacar elemento de array de objetos JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax

Cuando coloco la sintaxis para sacar elemento de un array de objetos JSON me marca error en un IF que tengo, pero cuando quito la sintaxis de sacar elemento el error se quita. No logro entender muy bien porque me manda ese error.

Les comparto el código esperando que me puedan apoyar a saber por qué.

**Array de objetos JSON (hice console.log de data del AJAX):**

```
data_cargos: (6) […]
0: Object { id: "1", id_grupo: "1", id_nivel: "2", … }
1: Object { id: "2", id_grupo: "1", id_nivel: "2", … }
2: Object { id: "3", id_grupo: "1", id_nivel: "2", … }
3: Object { id: "4", id_grupo: "2", id_nivel: "2", … }
4: Object { id: "5", id_grupo: "2", id_nivel: "2", … }
5: Object { id: "6", id_grupo: "2", id_nivel: "2", … }
length: 6
data_grupos: (4) […]
0: Object { id: "1", descripcion: "Docentes", deleted: "0" }
1: Object { id: "2", descripcion: "Directivos", deleted: "0" }
2: Object { id: "4", descripcion: "Servicios", deleted: "0" }
3: Object { id: "17", descripcion: "Prueba", deleted: "0" }
length: 4
data_niveles: (3) […]
0: Object { id: "1", descripcion: "Inicial", deleted: "0" }
1: Object { id: "2", descripcion: "Primario", deleted: "0" }
2: Object { id: "3", descripcion: "Secundario", deleted: "0" }
length: 3
data_persona_condicion: (2) […]
0: Object { id: "1", descripcion: "Católico", feriados_especiales: "1", … }
1: Object { id: "2", descripcion: "Judío", feriados_especiales: "1", … }
length: 2
data_proveedores: (3) […]
0: Object { id: "1", descripcion: "PUZZLE WebLines", deleted: "0" }
1: Object { id: "2", descripcion: "SITECO S.A.", deleted: "0" }
2: Object { id: "3", descripcion: "ServiLimp S.R.L.", deleted: "0" }
length: 3
```

**Función para sacar el elemento (En el if me manda el error):**

```js
function getDataComboID(id_grupo, id_nivel, id_cargo, id_condicion){
      $.ajax({
          url : "<?=base_url();?>Personas/getDataCombo",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "JSON",
          success: function(data) {
            // limpio el combo
            $('#combo-empleado-grupo option').remove(); // clear all values
            $('#combo-empleado-nivel option').remove(); // clear all values
            $('#combo-empleado-cargo option').remove(); // clear all values
            $('#combo-empleado-condicion option').remove(); // clear all values

            var select_grupo = document.getElementById("combo-empleado-grupo"); //Seleccionamos el select
            var select_nivel = document.getElementById("combo-empleado-nivel"); //Seleccionamos el select
            var select_cargo = document.getElementById("combo-empleado-cargo"); //Seleccionamos el select
            var select_condicion = document.getElementById("combo-empleado-condicion"); //Seleccionamos el select
            console.log(data);
            // saco la linea de la empresa
            $.each(data.data_grupos, function (index, value){
              // EN ESTE IF ME MANDA ERROR
              if (value.id == id_grupo) {
                const value = data.data_grupos.splice(index, 1);
                
              }
            });
        
            for(var i = 0; i < data.data_grupos.length; i++){ 
                var option = document.createElement("option"); //Creamos la opcion
                option.innerHTML = data.data_grupos[i].descripcion; //Metemos el texto en la opción
                option.value = data.data_grupos[i].id;
                select_grupo.appendChild(option); //Metemos la opción en el select
            }

            
          },
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert("datos incorrectos");
          }
      });
    }
```

Error (solo manda el error cuando coloco el splice para sacar los elementos, pero cuando quito la sintaxis desaparece el error)

> Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "id", value is undefined

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos y bonito día.

Comment: ¿Qué obtienes si antes de la comparación agregas `console.log(value);`? Recuerda que la depuración consiste en saber lo que contiene cada variable u objeto, es lo único que puede darte pistas para solucionar el problema. Si no tienes los valores esperados, entonces, antes del ciclo agrega `console.log(data.data_grupos);` y, si aún no ves los valores adecuados, entonces `console.log(data);` para ver desde dónde viene el error.

Comment: Dentro del ciclo estás redefiniendo `value`, eso ya es un problema.

Comment: Ya imprimi esos datos en consola y todo sale bien (imprimir value)

Comment: Object { id: "1", descripcion: "Docentes", deleted: "0" }
Personas:975:23
Object { id: "2", descripcion: "Directivos", deleted: "0" }
Personas:975:23
Object { id: "3", descripcion: "Administrativos", deleted: "0" }
Personas:975:23
Object { id: "17", descripcion: "Prueba", deleted: "0" }
Personas:975:23
undefined

Comment: Dos cosas: 1. Intenta sin redefinir `value` 2. Si quieres eliminar elementos que corresponden a determinado grupo, lo mejor es filtrar: [Opción con jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/), [Opción Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

Comment: Es que lo que intento hacer es llenar el combo box porque voy a  hacer un update, entonces colo tal quiero sacar ese elemento que sea igual al del usuario que quiero editar para posteriormente insertarlo al final del array y ahora si hacer el llenado del combo que vendría siendo la parte del ciclo for.

Comment: @Triby ya quedo, utilice mejor otro ciclo for en lugar del each. Muchas gracias!